# Internet Explorer: fadeIn(); and position: absolute;

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem using fadeIn() on div that contains elements which positions are absolute. Earlier I made a post but it seems that people did not understand my problem because I did not put it clearly enough.
Here is a code example, works on every browser except IE - http://jsfiddle.net/Ayy6W/3/

The reason I need this is because I want to create something similar to http://www.timmacpherson.com/ but using jQuery instead of Flash. So I need to put those horizontal lines and texts manually on my fixed sized wrapper. I hope you understand what I'm trying to do here and maybe there is some other way.

Comment: What exactly is not working? You are hiding and showing the #hello div at the same time (almost).

Comment: More specifically, it's `fadeIn` on an element containing an absolutely positioned element.  `fadeIn` on the element that is absolutely positioned seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably have found, this is a [common bug](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/temporary-fix-for-ie-fadein-fadeout-fadeto-bug-not-working) in IE.  One solution would be to wrap the faded element in an absolutely positioned element and have the faded element display inline-block.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayy6W/14/)'s the updated fiddle that uses this method.

**UPDATE**

Another option based on your comment is to do just that:  iterate over the different elements you want to fade in.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/Ayy6W/28/) is an example where you add the `fadeIn` class to each element and then iterate over them individually.  In that case, the javascript would be as follows:

```
$("#hello .fadeIn").each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Okey, but what if I need to fadein whole div containing many elements that are using absolute position? It seems that with this fix I have to fadeIn() every element.

Comment: @Qmal I've added a potential solution that handles the case mentioned in your comment.