# jQuery fadeIn not working with position attribute (In Internet Explorer)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Why jQuery fadeIn() not working with position css attribute in IE. All other browsers are fine.

Please see this in IE
http://jsfiddle.net/Ayy6W/56/

Comment: my apologies, forgot to mention that this is only IE issue (all versions).

Comment: I don't think the question is useful in its current form. "Why" is answered simply by "It's IE". And I don't mean that in a smug way at all; I just mean that if it works in all other browsers, then there is a browser-specific problem and the code is fine.

Comment: completely agree with you Greg by """it's IE""" :). Any solution/hack/trick welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a strange inheritance issue in the IE rendering engine, absolute elements can't inherit opacity from a parent unless that parent is positioned relatively. Don't ask me why, I don't know, but it's the case.

```
#rollover {
    position:relative;
}
```

Is all that's needed to be added to the CSS and it functions perfectly in IE.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ayy6W/59/

Comment: Just discovered this is also the case for Chrome. I changed the position of my async draggable elements from `fixed` to `relative` and now `fadeIn()` works.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayy6W/58/) according to answers to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6430540/944681). This could work as a workaround..